# Why does copying large files use up all of my available RAM?

Tags: performance

My laptop is a Dell Latitude E5530. It has 8G RAM and an i5 processor. It is normally lightning fast.

I copied some files over from my Iomega 500G hard drive which were stored in a Maciom Reflect image file and pasted them in my C: drive.

Next thing I know, during and AFTER the copying, my computer is dead slow. Physical Memory: 94%.

What is going on?

**EDIT:**:  I removed the hard drive and the computer I think has sped up.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Check the Task Manager to determine what process was using your memory.  Does this happen often?

Comment: only when I coyy from this large hard drive. Nothing appears to be using a lot of memory in the Task Manager

Comment: What method are you using for copying?  i.e. Windows Explorer copy&paste will behave very different from xcopy at command line, still different from robocopy ....

Comment: @Debra and for each of those things you mention (as if you might have knowledge of how they behave differently with respect to ram), you say nothing about how they behave differently (specifically with respect to ram). information that might actually help people and that'd make a very informative useful comment or answer for many people. (If indeed you're correct about what you suggest, the little that you have suggested, and I have some doubt even on that!)

Answer (score 0):

When copying files, both large and small, Windows reads the file into RAM (memory), as it copies it to the new destination it continuously frees up memory. The rate at which this memory is freed up depends on how fast Windows can write to the destinations' storage.

Evidently there is some sort of corruption with the file so Windows simply loaded it into memory and then could not do anything with it until you disconnected your external HDD. Upon disconnecting your HDD, Windows essentially says "well, i don't care about this file anymore, you can have your memory back"

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap

This program has an option to clear certain types of used memory while copying. During long copies you have to use it over and over again to keep memory freed.
Problem occurs with robocopy xcopy or unpacking archives.
There is no option in windows so far i know to prevent this.
Problem with Windows copy if the total size of files to copy is larger than the free disk space it will not copy, even if lots of files are already present on the destination drive that you do not want to overwrite. Its just a few of the 10-thousands of flaws on Windows.
It is all done on purpose to keep you handicapt and busy.